# Show that a metric is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am considering the metric space $(M,d)$, where $M$ is nonempty. I define $\rho:M\times M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\rho(x,y):=\dfrac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$. I have shown that $\rho$ is also a metric on $M$ and that $d$ and $\rho$ are equivalent. Now I want to show that $M$ is bounded with respect to $\rho$, but I do not really understand how I can show this. Has someone a hint for me?

Comment: Note that $\rho(x,y) < 1$ for all $x,y \in M$.

Comment: @Randall your proposed duplicate has no answers showing that the metric is bounded; they all seem to assume it instead.

Comment: You are correct: I missed this.  Vote to reopen.

Comment: I've voted to reopen since, as postmortes points out, the linked post doesn't answer this question.  I expect this question is a duplicate, but not to any part of that question.

Comment: @Charlie, thnx. I thought that this question should be more complex, but I now indeed see that $\rho(x,y)\in[0,1)$ and that M is thus bounded